# Nuxt Auth redirection for logged in users does not work in static mode

Tags: authentication, redirect, nuxt.js, production-environment

I have a Nuxt app where the "/" route is the sign-up page and as soon as a user signs up and logs in, they are redirected to the "/dashboard" route. The intended behaviour is for logged in users to get redirected to "/dashboard" even if they navigate to the index page of the website and this seems to work locally with `yarn dev`, but not in production and not when I run `nuxt generate` followed by `nuxt start`. In production, if I navigate to the "/" route, I see the sign-up page and all the buttons appear to be unclickable, the only way to get out of this is to manually add the "/dashboard" route.

The website in question is [sleeprescue.org](https://www.sleeprescue.org) in case you'd like to try out this behaviour. Note that I'm using Nuxt.js 2.15.3 with [Nuxt Auth](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/) for authentication. You can find my auth config [here](https://github.com/ivan-rivera/sleep_rescue_client/blob/master/nuxt.config.js#L109), here is the gist:

```
auth: {
    localStorage: true,
    watchLoggedIn: true,
    redirect: {
      login: '/',
      logout: '/',
      home: '/dashboard',
    },
    strategies: {
      cookie: {
        cookie: {
          name: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
        },
        endpoints: {
          csrf: {
            url: '',
          },
        },
      },
      local: {
        scheme: 'refresh',
        token: {
          property: 'data.access_token',
          maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 90,
          type: '',
        },
        user: {
          property: false,
        },
        refreshToken: {
          property: 'data.renewal_token',
          maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 90,
          type: '',
        },
        endpoints: {
          login: { url: '/v1/session', method: 'post' },
          logout: { url: '/v1/session', method: 'delete' },
          refresh: { url: '/v1/session/renew', method: 'post' },
          user: { url: '/v1/user', method: 'get', propertyName: false },
        },
      },
    },
  },
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this error would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I am answering to help others with a similar issue. Add `callback: '/dashboard'` to the `redirect` object.

When you do, your config should look like this:

```json
redirect: {
      login: "/",
      logout: "/",
      callback: "/dashboard",
      home: "/dashboard",
    }
```